# Nested JSON with lists and dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I am trying to extract a nested JSON into a dataframe with the following structure:

```
[
{'id': '1','sort': 'kg', 'name': 'meal','detail': 
   [
       {'subid': 'A', 'name': 'Example','values': 
       [
          {'value': '3', 'time': 0320},
          {'value': '4', 'time': 0330},
```

I tried to extract with json_normalize but I get stuck with the second level 'values'. I think it has something to do with the number of levels that can be used with normalize. Is there another way to get this structure in a dataframe?

Code I have is:

```
myJsonResponse = json.loads(response.content)
objects = pd.json_normalize(myJsonResponse, record_path='detail', meta=['id','sort','name'], errors='ignore', meta_prefix='data_')
objects.explode('values')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh1An.png)

Comment: What do you want it to look like when this is done, exactly?  Are there many id's and sub id's here?

Comment: Thnk for the reply. I want to have a dateframe with all the fields as columns, so with id, sort, name, subid, name, value and time

Comment: This is my example (see in the original post) In the red rectangle the one that also needs to be extracted to columns. Is this possible with normalize?

Comment: There are good examples for this.  You have two nested structures, so you need two record_paths: `record_path=['detail','values']`.  You do have a problem that there are `name` keys at both levels.    You may have to expand the data by hand, which would not be hard.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply and solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as elegant as a one-liner, but this will handle the multiple nesting levels:

```
jsondata = [
        {'id': '1','sort': 'kg', 'name': 'meal','detail': 
            [
                {'subid': 'A', 'name': 'Example','values': 
                    [
                        {'value': '3', 'time': 320},
                        {'value': '4', 'time': 330},
                        {'value': '5', 'time': 340}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

import pandas as pd

rows = []
for d1 in jsondata:
    row = {}
    row.update( d1 )
    del row['detail']
    for d2 in d1['detail']:
        row['subid'] = d2['subid']
        row['namex'] = d2['name']
        for d3 in d2['values']:
            row.update(d3)
            rows.append( row )

o = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatten_json

```
from flatten_json import flatten

jsondata = [
        {'id': '1','sort': 'kg', 'name': 'meal','detail': 
            [
                {'subid': 'A', 'name': 'Example','values': 
                    [
                        {'value': '3', 'time': 320},
                        {'value': '4', 'time': 330},
                        {'value': '5', 'time': 340}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

    
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in jsondata)
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
```

Output

```
  id sort  name detail.0.subid detail.0.name detail.0.values.0.value  detail.0.values.0.time detail.0.values.1.value  detail.0.values.1.time detail.0.values.2.value  detail.0.values.2.time
0  1   kg  meal              A       Example                       3                     320                       4                     330                       5                     340
```

Comment: Thnks for your reply